# Unshelve to a new changelist from command line

Tags: cmd, perforce

With the perforce GUI, it's possible to unshelve files from a pending changelist into a new changelist. I noticed in the log that the GUI program accomplishes this by first creating a new empty changelist and then unshelving into that new changelist.

How would one do this from a batch script? I have a list of shelved changelists and I would like to unshelve each of them into new pending changelists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash function version:

```
# Takes shelved changeset # as single argument and unshelves to a new changeset
p4unshelve() {
    p4 change -i <<< "Change:new"$'\n'"Description:Unshelve $1" | awk '{ print $2 }' | p4 unshelve -s $1 -c $(cat)
}
```

Usage

```
p4unshelve 43245
```

This will not work as-is in a .bat file but could be used if you are using some form of Bash and could probably be modified to it's .bat counterpart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please help in improving it by appending the original changelist description in the new changelist description?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [changes](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html) command with the `-s shelved` option to retrieve a list of all your shelved changes.

If you create a new changelist for each shelved change, the `-c <changelist>` option of the [unshelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_unshelve.html) command allows you to specify the destination changelist.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to be able to do this in an automated way, which doesn't require me to create a changelist and remember the changelist number. Is there a way to do what you've suggested from a cmd script?

Comment: In a batch script, I'm not sure. In Python, it should be pretty easy. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Creating a new changelist from the command line is so tedious. Can't believe there is no way to invoke p4 change and get a new empty changelist without providing a change specification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell cmdlet to create a new numbered changelist:

```
function New-Changelist {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Message
    )
    process {
        $cl = p4 --field "Description=$Message" --field "Files=" change -o | 
            p4 change -i | 
            select-string "\b(\d+)" | 
            ForEach-Object {$_.matches[0].value}

        Write-Output $cl
    }
}
```

It outputs the changelist number, so you can easily add that to the unshelve command:

```
$cl = New-Changelist -Message "Changelist for unshelving"
p4 unshelve -s 99999 -c $cl
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not pretty but if you have a shelved changelist number that you want to unshelve into a new changelist you can run the following:

```
 (echo Change:  new && echo Description:    test) | p4 change -i | for /f "tokens=2" %i IN ('more') DO p4 unshelve -s 99999 -c %i
```

If you know of a cleaner solution, please post it.

Comment: Why not just unshelve into the default changelist? Why do you need a numbered changelist? Just run 'p4 unshelve -s NNN' and shelf NNN will be unshelved into the default changelist.

Comment: @Bryan Because I'm reviewing the changelists from someone else and want to keep them separate for ease of reference. I didn't know that such a seemingly simple task would prove so difficult for p4's command line tools.

Comment: It does take a bit of time to get used to. Do you need to review all these changelists together? Or are you reviewing each separately? If they are each distinct, then you can do 'p4 revert //...' in between each review session, and then you can re-use the default changelist each time. Creating numbered changelists for changes that you never plan to submit is fine, but eventually you accumulate a lot of empty numbered changelists.

Comment: Another thing you can do, if you only need to look at the diffs for the shelf, rather than actually build and test with it, is to run just 'p4 describe -S NNN', and then you see the diffs for the shelf without having to actually unshelve it.

Comment: If you just want to review/test other people's changes, I think you're best off creating a separate client just for that purpose.  Then you can keep your own changes separate from other people's and use the default changelist as @BryanPendleton suggested.

Comment: I don't understand why an answer for _bash_ on my question tagged for _cmd_ has +2 upvotes, but my answer with a working one-liner in cmd has -1.